# OpenAI-Java producing an error retrofit http-400

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 400 
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:57)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:38)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:48)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:35)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2517)
    at io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet(Single.java:2001)
    at com.theokanning.openai.OpenAiService.createCompletion(OpenAiService.java:91)
    at net.Amogh.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

is throwin by

```
OpenAiService service = new OpenAiService("yes i put correct token");
        CompletionRequest completionRequest = CompletionRequest.builder()
                .prompt("Hi")
                .echo(true)
                .build();
        service.createCompletion(completionRequest).getChoices().forEach(System.out::println);
```

im not sure why this is happening. does anyone know why and how to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try providing once with model argument as well...
completionRequest = CompletionRequest.builder().prompt("Hi").model("ada").echo(true).build();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).